# Uploaded file not saving in the directory (PHP AJAX) "Serious in Need"

Tags: php, html, ajax

So i try this simple upload code but it doesn't work properly for me.
As cFos Speed shows the file uploading process is OK and 150kb pic is uploading, but at the end the file is not in the directory.
Also mkdir doesn't create a new folder. although i gave all permissions such az rwx chmod and apache:apache chown completely to the files i'm working on.
Here's the codes for html and ajax :

```
<input type="file" name="authform" id="authform" accept="image/png">
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
        $("#authform").on("change", function()
        {
                var input = $(this);
                var inputLength = input[0].files.length;
                var file;
                var formData = new FormData();
                for (var i = 0; i < inputLength; i++)
                {
                        file = input[0].files[i];
                        formData.append( 'authform[]', file);
                };
                        $.ajax({
                        url: "file_upload.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: formData,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
});
```

and for the file_upload.php:

```
<?php
if (!file_exists('uploads')) {
    mkdir('uploads', 0777);
}

$filename = time()."_".$_FILES['file']['name'];

 if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'])  {
        echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
    }
    else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'downloads/user-files/' . $filename);
   }

echo 'downloads/user-files/'.$filename;
die;
?>
```

And Yes! i used a different directory because as said before mkdir does not work...
So what do you suggest guys?

Comment: Setup some proper error reporting in PHP. Then the script most probably will tell you where the error is.

Comment: Actually i did a good one, but it shows nothing just nothing except that mkdir.
"mkdir(): Permission denied'
doesn't show anything about upload process...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was I should have done this with copy() instead of move_uploaded_file().
I only needed a Form with enctype="multipart/form-data" and input with type="file", then with a submit action do this:

```
copy($_FILES['authform']['tmp_name'], "/var/www/html/test/app/downloads/user-files/" . $_FILES['authform']['name']);
```

And that's it! Works like a gem!

Answer (score 0):

Your file input does not have the `multiple` attribute so there is no need to loop through it as it will only have one file associated with it.

```
    $("#authform").on("change", function()
    {
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('authform', this.files[0]);
            $.ajax({
                url: "file_upload.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false
            });
    });
```

In your php code you refer to the file with the parameter `file` but you set it to `authform` in the js.

```
<?php
if (!file_exists('uploads')) {
    mkdir('uploads', 0777);
}

$filename = time()."_".$_FILES['authform']['name'];

 if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'])  {
        echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['authform']['error'] . '<br>';
    }
    else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['authform']['tmp_name'], 'downloads/user-files/' . $filename);
   }

echo 'downloads/user-files/'.$filename;
die;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately it didn't work either, i'm really confused idk why i'm having problem with such simple code....